# Extending Postgresql extension Postgis with a C extension in Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have some C code that is used on a Ubuntu server to create some extension to PostGIS. Now I want to install those functions on my Windows server (Where I now want to run my PostgreSQL server from). I manage to setup one Visual Studio solution but I got a lot of failing includes.

I downloaded the PostGIS and PostgreSQL source code and included them in the Visual Studio solution dependencies. However, I can't find the liblwgeom.h to be able to use POINT2D etc. From what I understood I need to build PostGIS as well in order to generate that file or where is it located in PostGIS 3.3.2 source code?

If I need to build PostGIS in order to get it, is there any updated guide or advice how to build it in a Windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

`liblwgeom/liblwgeom.h` will be generated from `liblwgeom/liblwgeom.h.in` during the `./configure` step.

The installation instructions are [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/postgis_installation.html#PGInstall), which works if you use the MinGW build toolchain. That is the easiest way to do it. Other than that, there is one page with [instructions for building on Windows](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiWinCompile).

Building extensions on Windows unfortunately still is quite complicated and hardly to be recommended for beginners.

Comment: ok, but I want to use Windows and `The following steps outline the configuration and compilation of the PostGIS source. They are written for Linux users and will not work on Windows or Mac.` So I don´t how much of help those are?

Comment: Oh, Windows... I have added what information there is, but by advice is not to use Windows.